# POD services in Kubernetes not opening from google cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I installed kubernetes 3 node cluster in google cloud virtual machines.All PODS are working fine inside the network but I am not able to expose the service url outside google cloud.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose the service itself, but you are not able to expose the service URL. The URL is only known to the Kubedns of your cluster.

If you would like to expose the service, I would suggest using a "Nodeport" or "LoadBalancer" type. You can read more about how to expose the service [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-services/).